# Use OpenTelemetry to track Kubernetes pods/containers cpu, memory and health

Tags: kubernetes, open-telemetry

Does opentelemetry provide auto instrumentation for Kubernetes pods/containers cpu, memory and health if I am using opentelemetry-collector-contrib?